# How to find layer ID and name from Identify query using ArcGIS Web ADF?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, .net, arcgis-web-adf

I need to retrieve the layer ID of every layer returned by the *IQueryFunctionality.Identify* function (I am using ADF with .NET)

Identify function spits out a *DataTable* array for layers which have answered to the query. Since there's no way to know what layers have not answered, you need to check the *TableName* (which is the layer name) for every *DataTable* in the array.

But what if you have two layers with the same name? You can't know what layer answered and what layer didn't

The closest answer I could find on the internet is a **[link at esri forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2276&t=240048&mc=7#msgid731658)** but the topic got disbanded before reaching a solution (which may not exist perhaps).

This sounds like a problem to me, can someone please help me?